# Difference Between C and Python Ternary Operators

Tags: python, c, ternary-operator

Well I just read a SOF thread where I see many people are talking about Python's ternary operator. I didn't know that Python has a ternary operator (ternary operator or conditional expression whatever you feel comfort with) equivalent though. So the syntax of Python ternary operator is...

```
play_golf if sun_shines else stay_dumb
```

Here Python will test the block `sun_shines` after if. If the block returns `true` it will execute the block `play_golf` before if otherwise Python will execute the block `stay_dumb` after else.

On the other hand I guess C's ternary operator is more readable.

```
sun_shines ? play_golf : stay_dumb
```

It is like asking a question `sun_shines`? True? Ok then `play_golf` otherwise `stay_dumb`.

Now my questions are...

- How Python is Pythonic here? "Simple is better than complex" failed here in my opinion. If I am wrong please clarify me. I want to know what I am missing?
- Execution order of C and Python conditional expression is completely different I see. So How it is equivalent of C? In the terms of folding multiple statements into one single expression?

**Edit:** I guess I got the answer to my 2nd question...

**Python:** `true if true else false`

**C:** `true ? true : false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my questions are...
>
> How Python is more Pythonic here? "Simple is better than complex" failed here in my opinion. If I am wrong please clarify me. I want to
>   know what I am missing?

The English sentence is

*we go to the beach if the weather is nice, else we stay at home*.

Highlight the right words, leave out the fillers:

```
gotobeach if weather == "nice" else stayathome
```

that looks a lot like valid Python ;)

> Execution order of C and Python conditional expression is completely different I see.

No. It's not.

First, the line is parsed, then the condition after if is evaluated, then either one of the statements is evaluated.

Comment: In fact in real life we don't talk in this way... gotobeach if weather == "nice" else stayathome

Rather I speak like... if weather is nice then go to beach else stay at home. Well I would ask my daughter... Weather is good? Ok then go to beach else stay at home. 

No problem with your opinion though. I see different people think differently. :)

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) which defines the conditional expression:

> Many C-derived languages use this syntax:
>
> ```
> <condition> ? <expression1> : <expression2>
> ```
>
> Eric Raymond even implemented this.  The BDFL rejected this for
>   several reasons: the colon already has many uses in Python (even
>   though it would actually not be ambiguous, because the question
>   mark requires a matching colon); for people not used to C-derived
>   language, it is hard to understand.

In the PEP you can find the motivations of the decision, I find those appropriate, however this is just a personal opinion.

The parsing order is not different from C, as said by @Marcus Muller.